# How to structure dashboard with schedule

Tags: website-design, design, web

So, in my current design I have something like this:

[image]

I have a dashboard that has a menu with a couple different options. In the 'home' option the user can see a schedule with their appointments if there are, the appointments waiting for confirmation, the next appointment and the last appointment in order to rate it. When the user clicks on start timer a timer stars and then changes the last appointment to the one that had previously had the timer.

Am I showing too much information to the user? Should the schedule be shown separately and include clicks to go see it whenever it would make sense to? Or should I have a even more reduced version than this schedule and then another schedule but with more functionalities?

Thanks!

Comment: can you elaborate a little more on what the highest priority here is? Is it starting the appt timer, and knowing what's active, then what is queued up? I don't see any confirmed 'next appts' , just proposed.

Comment: @MikeM Highest priority as in what is the most important thing to make sure the user understands? It should flow naturally for the user, accepts appt, then eventually has to start a timer for that appointment and once that ends passes to last appointment. Do you think it would make sense to have a list of next appointments? Sorry if I misunderstood anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three very different sections to the screen you shared. One has to do with a schedule at a glance for 7 days, one is responding to what could be notifications/requests for appointments and one is for actions that I need to taken my current job or just completed ones.

Feels like these should all be separate pages:

1. Calendar View to see your whole week
2. Work screen which is what you see when you are working and looking at your current appointment and the next one
3. Notifications of new requests and a screen to accept and reject them

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much. Only one question, when you click a notification showing a request, what you suggest is to be taken to a new screen showing ALL notifications (with the one clicked higlighted) then showing accept or reject options?

Comment: @levon you can probably do both, allow them to accept/reject from the notification itself and also they can click to view all notifications to go to a full screen view